# How to prove that infinitely small and large numbers can be used as measures of rates of convergence?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

I read "Lectures on the Hyperreals: An Introduction to Nonstandard Analysis" Robert Goldblatt.

He wrote that infinitely small and large numbers can be used as measures of rates of convergence.
[image]

It's intuitively clear for me.
But how to prove this in rigorously way? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: that's what the rest of the book is going to be about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequences $x=(1,2,3,4,\ldots)$ and $y=(2,4,6,8,\ldots)$ satisfy the relation $y=2x$ and therefore so do their equivalence classes $[x]$ and $[y]$, so that $[y]=2[x]$ in the hyperreals.  But we know that all nonzero real numbers $r$ satisfy $r\not=2r$.  Therefore by the transfer principle, the inequality holds for all hyperreals, and in particular $[x]\not=[y]$.

Note that Goldblatt is not a historian and his historical claims should be taken with a grain of salt, including the assertion that

> According to Cauchy, the sequence $1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots$ is an infinitesimal.

Cauchy specifically does *not* say that.  Rather, Cauchy says in his *Cours d'Analyse* that such a sequence *becomes* an infinitesimal (implying a change of nature).  For further details, see [British Journal for the History of Mathematcs](https://doi.org/10.1080/26375451.2020.1770015) and the references cited there.

Comment: I don't fully understand your proof. Why do you say about inequality?

Comment: @Mike_bb, you wanted to know why the two sequences give *distinct* hyperreal numbers, as claimed by Goldblatt.  That's what I tried to explain.

Comment: I want to know how to prove that infinitesimal or large numbers and rates of convergence are related.

Comment: The idea is that the infinitely large number corresponding to a sequence (via the ultrapower construction) *is* (more precisely, can be viewed as; alternatively, "represents a measure of") the rate of convergence.  The fact that $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ goes to infinity slower than $2,4,6,8,\ldots$ is supposed to be illustrated by the fact that the hyperreal corresponding to the sequence $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ is smaller than the hyperreal corresponding to the sequence $2,4,6,8,\ldots$.  @Mike_bb

Comment: Incidentally, I have a set of lecture notes on the hyperreals that is based on Goldblatt and is supposed to be more accessible than Goldblatt, including an introductory chapter with a discussion at the level of infinitesimal calculus (which Goldblatt does not have).  This can be seen at https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/coursenotes.pdf